# swift update frame of uitableviewcell with uiswipegesturerecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I added an `UISwipeGestureRecogniser` into my tableviewcell. Now I'd like to add a real time slide effect to my tableviewcell. If I currently swipe over the cell nothing happens. The cell should just be swipeable.

My code:

```
var originalCenter = CGPoint()

var rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleSwipes:"))
rightSwipe.direction = .Right
self.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

func handleSwipes(recogniser:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    let location : CGPoint = recogniser.locationInView(self)

    if (recogniser.direction == .Right) {

        if recogniser.state == .Began {

            // when the gesture begins, record the current center location
            originalCenter = center
        }

        if recogniser.state == .Changed {

            let translation = recogniser.locationInView(self)
            center = CGPointMake(originalCenter.x + translation.x, originalCenter.y)
        }

        if recogniser.state == .Ended {

        }

        println("Swipe Right")
    }
}
```

Comment: You set up a UIPanGestureRecognizer but you keep referring to swiping. If you only need to be able to swipe you can set up a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and set its direction.

Comment: I updated my code with a `uiswipegesturerecognizer` but I don't know why the cell doesn't change it's position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have custom cell swipes implemented in my previous projects... you need to animate the things to look exactly like the swipe which works in notification draw message swiping. I can give you snippet in Objective-C. you should be able to translate it into swift easily ;)

```
-(void)handleLeftCellSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
     CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.localTableView];
     NSIndexPath *swipedIndexPath = [self.localTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
     UITableViewCell *swipedCell  = [self.localTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:swipedIndexPath];
     if(swipedCell){
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.7 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
          [swipedCell.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(swipedCell.contentView.frame.origin.x - 40, swipedCell.contentView.frame.origin.y, swipedCell.contentView.frame.size.width, swipedCell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
          } completion:^(BOOL finished){
              // Do whatever you need to do after animation completes
          }];
     }
}
```

Comment: I got the first part (`var location = recogniser.locationInView(tableView)
        var swipedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location)
        var swipedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(swipedIndexPath!) as UITableViewCell?
`) but don't know how I can get further (I'm still learning Swift). Could you please help me to translate the 2nd part?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do what you want to do by subclassing UIPanGestureRecognizer. But don't. Instead of adding a gesture recognizer, turn your cell into a UIScrollView. Now you can set its `contentSize` and bounds origin so that it can be scrolled left to right only. The advantage here is that you are using a built-in interface class that is made to be draggable automatically. You can use the delegate methods to keep track of what the user does if you need to.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my updated question?

Comment: Could you please consider doing what I said? Obviously the cell won't go anywhere as things stand; you are not doing anything to make it move. But the scrollable content of a scroll view inside the cell _can_ go somewhere.